# Extracting data from excel using python and writing to an empty excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis

I have a large set of data that I am trying to extract from multiple excel files that have multiple sheets using python and then write that data into a new excel file. I am new with python and have tried to use various tutorials to come up with code that can help me automate the process. However, I have reached a point where I am stuck and need some guidance on how to write the data that I extract to a new excel file. If someone could point me in the write direction, it would be greatly appreciated. See code below:

```
import os
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
path = r"Path where all excel files are located"
os.chdir(path)
for WorkingFile in os.listdir(path):
   if os.path.isfile(WorkingFile):
      DataFrame = pd.read_excel(WorkingFile, sheet_name = None, header = 12, skipfooter = 54)
DataFrame.to_excel(r'Empty excel file where to write all the extracted data')
```

When I execute the code I get an error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'. So I am not sure how to rectify this error, any help would be appreciated.

Little bit more background on what I am trying to do. I have a folder with about 50 excel files, each file might have multiple sheets. The data I need is located on a table that consists of one row and 14 columns and is in the same location on each file and each sheet. I need to pull that data and compile it into a single excel file. When I run the code above and and a print statement, it is showing me the exact data I want but when I try to write it to excel it doesn't work.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: `DataFrame` is a `dict` of dataframes in case you're reading in multiple sheets, as explained under the `sheet_name` parameter in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: Yes, when I check type(DataFrame) it shows dict. How would one go about converting to dataframes? Do I need to rethink my code or can it be modified so it does what I want?

Comment: You could probably take inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881051/python-pandas-write-dataframe-to-csv). Or iterate over the `.items()` in the dict.

Comment: You are re-defining the function DataFrame, (`DataFrame = pd.read_excel(...)`) this is bad, definitively you shouldn't do that. Also, in your code yo didn't import pandas as pd, it looks like your code is incomplete.

Comment: I believe I forgot to add it to my code here but in my original code I do have the line import as pandas as pd at the top. I’ll check when I have access to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're importing DataFrame instead of pandas. Looks like your code is incomplete. Below code will clear the doubts you have. (Not include any conditions for excluding non excel files/dir etc )

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = "Dir path to excel files" #Path

df = pd.DataFrame() # Initialize empty df

for file in os.listdir(path):

     data = pd.read_excel(path + file) # Read each file from dir
     df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True) # and append to empty df


# process df

df.to_excel("path/file.xlsx")
```